# Inserting a Pause into a Mapping Using the PubMed Service Request

Tags: webservices

For a number of years I have been compiling a comprehensive bibliography of works that include mention of fishes of the family Scorpaenidae. Consequently, I am always on the lookout for datasets that can be mined for this purpose.

Recently, I learned that I could use this method to automatically search the PubMed database:

```
pubmed = ServiceConnect["PubMed"]

scorpaenidaeSearch = pubmed["PublicationSearch", "Query" -> "Scorpaenidae", 
  MaxItems -> 1000, "Elements" -> "FullData"]
```

I am able to get much of the pertinent data directly (although it only seems to return recent publications). From this I can obtain a lists of the UID's or the located publications by using the following commands.

```
scorpSearch = Values[Normal[scorpaenidaeSearch]]
scorpSearch[[All, 1]]
```

However, the "FullData" parameter does not return the publication
abstract. For an individual UID I can obtain the corresponding Abstract using

```
pubmed["PublicationAbstract", "ID" -> "37344374"]
```

However, I can't figure out the syntax to generate the abstracts
from a list of UID's, without violating the NCBI limit of requesting
not more than one request every 3 seconds.

**How can I place Pause[5] into the following mapping to generate
abstracts for the list of UID's obtained using the UID's returned
via the following command?**

```
abstracts = 
  pubmed["PublicationAbstract", "ID" -> #] & /@ scorpSearch[[All, 1]]
```

I've tried to construct a Do loop for this purpose, but can not construct an appropriate syntax for the mapping.  Without a pause, the mapping violates the rate limit on the service and the request is denied.  The following does not work.

```
 abstracts = 
  Do[Pause[5]; pubmed["PublicationAbstract", "ID" -> String[#]] &, 125] /@ 
  scorpSearch[[All, 1]]
```

(125 records are returned for this particular search)

Nor does:

```
abstracts = (pubmed["PublicationAbstract", "ID" -> ToString[#]] &;
  Pause[5]) /@ scorpSearch[[All, 1]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
uids = Normal @ scorpaenidaeSearch[All, "UID"]

abstracts = {};

Do[Pause[5]; 
 AppendTo[abstracts, 
  pubmed["PublicationAbstract", "ID" -> ToString[i]]], 
 {i, uids}]
```

View abstracts 5 and 6:

```
Row[Panel /@ abstracts[[5 ;; 7]]]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "13.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"
> ```

Comment: Code as written works for reading records from abstracts.  However, when placed into following write stream it generates an error without creating the file.

Comment: stream = OpenWrite[scorpaenidaeAbstractFile]
Write[stream, abstracts[[All]]]
Close[stream]URLFetch::invhttp: A library error occurred. The raw details are: "libcurl error (18): transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining"

Comment: @StuartPoss, I was able to run the code `s = OpenWrite["testfile"];
Write[s, abstracts]` to create a file without any error messages (version 13.3.0 for Linux x86). Try putting `Close[stream` in a separate cell after executing `Write[stream,abstracts]` - if that does not work you might consider posting the issue as a new question.